# Labelling and specifying bins in histograms in Julia

Tags: julia, histogram

I'm trying to plot a histogram in Julia. For illustrative purposes, in the example below I plot `age`, which ranges from `0 to 100`.

```
age = 100*rand(1000,1)
histogram(age, xlabel = "Age", bins = range(0,100, step = 5),
            xticks = 0:5:100, leg = false)
```

Ideally I'd want to:

1. Have the first bin include all values smaller than 20, and the last all greater than 60. The other bins should be just as above, `step = 5`.
2. Be able to label the bins, in particular to have `< 20` and `> 60`.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the `Plots` plotting package (it's good to make this explicitly in your question, as there are many mature plotting packages in Julia with different syntax and functionality).

To your first question, it's useful to `clamp` your age vector, so that all values below 20 are set to 19, and all values above 60 are set to 61.

On the second point, you can just set the `xticks` including labels explicitly:

```
julia> histogram(clamp.(age, 19, 61), bins = 10; xlabel = "Age", leg = false,
                 xticks = ([17.5; 20:5:60; 62.5], ["<20"; 20:5:60; ">60"]), xrot = 45)
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: instead of `clamp` I would perhaps prefer: `bins = [0, 20:5:60...,100]`

Comment: That's what I did initially actually, the problem with that is that the 0-20 bin then actually goes from 0 to 20. That might or might not be preferably, visually I preferred the `clamp` approach.